# Google Calendar API in iOS and Cross Client Authorization

Tags: ios, google-api, cross-platform, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

We have an iOS app that uses Google oAuth to ask a users permission for Google calendar using embedded browser. User logs in via the app and grants permission to their calendar(s), the oAuth authorization's refresh token and calendar id's are stored in an encrypted database.
Using this refresh token and calendar id's - their calendar items would then be displayed on a separate web application (without having to request for clients credentials again). This worked great until Google authorization requests in embedded browsers were blocked on April 20 this year. Until this time we used a single oAuth client id and used the client id & secret in both the iOS and the Web app. However, after April 20th, we had to create a separate iOS client key. The issue now is that although within the iOS app we are able to ask for users calendar permissions using this code:

`OIDAuthorizationRequest *request = [[OIDAuthorizationRequest alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration
                                   clientId:GoogleCustomKey
                                   scopes:@[OIDScopeOpenID,
                                   OIDScopeProfile, OIDScopeEmail, @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
                                   @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
                                   @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks",
                                   @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly"]
                                   redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:GoogleRedirectUri]
                                   responseType:OIDResponseTypeCode
                                   additionalParameters:nil];`

However now we are no longer able to display the users calendars using the refresh token on the web application. Within the web application, we get "Unauthorized access" error when we debug the web application code. But according to Google's documentation cross client authorization is permitted https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth.
We are not sure what we are missing? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried going to Google Dev Console and generating a new clientID and use that instead? Seems like an expired clientID or expired access token.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. Token is valid else would have gotten an expired token error instead. I believe it might be due to the fact that in the iOS code we haven't authorized the Web application using: audience:server:client_id:. This is based on this document for cross client authentication:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth. But still trying to find out how we need to attach the audience:server:client_id aspect when we call it in iOS. If anyone has this info, please respond. thanks.